# How to correctly infer Svelte props type?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I have a svelte component (SvelteKit Project) - let's call it `MyComponent`. It accepts *two* props.

What would be the correct way to do it with TypeScript?

### Option 1: Type-cast the `$$props`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    interface ComponentPropType {
        a: string;
        b: number;
    }

    export let { a, b } = $$props as ComponentPropType;
</script>

<h1>a = {a} </h1>
<p>My value is {b} </p>
```

Or should I go with a bit verbose

### Option 2: De-structure the props specified by `export let`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    interface ComponentPropType {
        a: string;
        b: number;
    }
    export let props: ComponentPropType;
    export let { a, b } = props;
</script>

<h1>a = {a} </h1>
<p>My value is {b} </p>
```

---

If we use **Option 1** -  we can render the component as `<MyComponent {{a, b}} />` or `<MyComponent {a} {b} />`
Does this one prevent event forwarding (if any)?

On the other hand, if we use **Option 2** - we need to render the component as `<MyComponent props={{a, b}} />`.
In this case, we can't use the prop-spread.

Which one is the correct way to do it? Is there a better solution?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here and would not use either of these. You can type each `export let ...` statement separately, there is no need for anything else.

Comment: How do you typecast the component `props` using a typescript `interface` or `type` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. (Also, TS has no casting, only type assertions, it does not change anything about the data, which can happen with casting.)

Comment: TS has casting. You can literally do something like `data as SomeType` or `<SomeType>data`. I think I'll look around for a better answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: It's *not* a cast, it changes nothing about the run-time type unlike in other languages. It just tells the compiler what type the value has (regardless of whether that is actually true), hence the term "[type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)", it merely asserts something about the type, nothing more.

Comment: Ok how do you type assert svelte component props using an interface?

Comment: Why? What is the point of adding an interface when you can type properties one at a time as you add them? Also, Svelte automatically generates a property interface based on the properties that are declared.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's necessary, but I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

What *should* be sufficient is to just define the props with `export let`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let a: string
    export let b: number;
</script>

<h1>a = {a} </h1>
<p>My value is {b} </p>
```

This will then be enough for you to use either direct assignment

`<Component a={"a"} b={2} />`

or spread

`<Component {...{a:"a", b:2}} />`

Note that the spread operator needs to be used, as `{{a,b}}` is not the same as `{...{a,b}}`

Comment: Hi Daniel, In the component you are declaring `prop a` and `prop b` separately using two `export` statements. My question was can I do something like
`export let {a, b}: CustomType` directly instead of writing it in a verbatim order?